# Is there any proverb/idiom about "climbing over the wall at night"?

Tags: translation, meaning, lyrics

Yes, even I find this question rather funny ;) But trying to translate a beautiful Chinese song titled "我對自己開了一槍" there's this part: 反正世事無常 沒必要在夜裡翻牆 And I'm cracking my mind wondering if it's a metaphor that there's no point in excessively trying to do something (in life general, because everything is fickle and unstable). Like it's even harder to climb a wall when it's dark, right? So just wait for some daylight. Or does it have any deeper meaning for native Chinese?

**Lyric:**

- 什麼狀況 其實不必講
- 反正人來人往 每個人都有傷
- 什麼難處 就讓他隨便滋長
- 反正世事無常 沒必要在夜裡翻牆
- 若不是真累了
- 怎允許讓身體漸漸的褪色

[我對自己開了一槍](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ro29toKIJZc)

Edit:
Indeed it's a song about "shooting oneself". Here's how I've translated the first stanza:

- What's the situation? Actually no need to explain
- People come and go anyway, everyone has wounds
- Despite any difficulty, let him grow as he wishes
- Everything is impermanent anyway. There is no need to climb over the
  wall at night
- If the body wasn't really tired
- How can I allow it to gradually fade?

I didn't find anything about "mortal world". Is it really there? I'm thinking about making a new topic about how and how often Chinese mention "a mortal world".

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://www.zhihu.com/question/21021240

Answer (score 1):

Not a happy bunny, the songwriter!

I found this on 百度:

逾墙越舍，汉语成语，拼音是yú qiáng yuè shě，意思是指翻墙越舍很快就走了。出自《原化记·崔慎思》

翻越：cross, surmount, transcend

意思是指翻墙越舍很快就走了
meaning is climb the walls abandon the house, flee

什麼狀況 其實不必講
No need to talk about any situation

反正人來人往 每個人都有傷
Anyway, people come and go, everybody hurts (shades of REM)

什麼難處 就讓他隨便滋長
Whatever the problem just let him develop freely (maybe *him* is actually *me*, an unhappy teenager?)

反正世事無常 沒必要在夜裡翻牆
Anyway in this mortal world there is no need to flee in the night

若不是真累了
If it weren't really tiring (too tired to die??)

怎允許讓身體漸漸的褪色
How to gradually just fade away? (Better to burn out, than to fade away! Neil Young)